# Determine existing binding for a special input function

Tags: fish

How do I determine how to invoke `backward-kill-bigword`? The docs for `bind` make it clear how to set a new binding, but not how to see the existing binding.

Answer (score 2):

Calling [bind](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/bind.html) without options lists all your existing bindings. Try this:

```
bind | grep backward-kill-bigword
```

Comment: You don't need the `--all` flag. Also, since arbitrary functions can be used in a binding the `backward-kill-bigword` might be in a function and thus won't show up in the grep output. That is unlikely but should be taken in to consideration.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I was just coming back to fix this. Fixed!